# Google Play app is incompatible with my phone

Tags: android, react-native, google-play

I have just published Android (React-Native) app on Google Play. It says:

```
Requires Android
5.0 and up
```

I did install the `apk` before on my Nexus 5 (Android 6.0 M). It worked just fine so I published it to Google Play. When I open Play from my browser I can't install the app on my Nexus from there (See Fido LGE Nexus 5):

[image]

I noticed, I can't find the app in Google Play when I try to search from Nexus:

- Is it because it is not indexed yet or because it's incompatible?
- Why would it be incompatible if I tested same `apk` on this phone prior publishing?

UPDATE:

feedback from support:

- Your app has an unsupported framework version: 17, 18, 19, and 20 in APK version 1 (Production)
- Your app has an incompatible screen: normal, 480 for Android Versions 17, 28, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24 and 25 in APK version 1 (Production)
- Your app is missing device feature: android.hardware.faketouch, android.hardware.location, android.hardware.screen.portrait for Android Versions 17, 18, 20 for APK version 1 (Production)

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me, I corrected it by setting minSdkVersion=whatever is minSdk required by your app in build.gradle of app. I tried everything in play console, nothing worked except this, and the strange thing was, same app with same source code worked just fine in Alpha version! Maybe some bug in play console. Just manually set the minSdkVersion manually, it is deprecated, but works.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll try it.

Comment: Do that and reupload the apk and mark the answer as correct if it works. I really need reputation on quora if i want to comment on something  Do try and tell if it worked.

Comment: Did you change it in AppManifest or gradle build file?

Comment: So there is one little thing, you should see which one is in the gradle, minSdkVersion or maxSdkVersion, as mine was minSdkVersion, I added maxSdkVersion to override play store default, as it was showing supported only for devices below Lollipop, whereas I made my app on device with Marshmallow! So you should see which one is present in build.gradle and then change according to your needs